# can you animate an image on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

since I'm learning new to html and javascript, I was wondering if you can place an moving image side to side on a canvas? If so how can this be done please???

Here's what I've to do so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ann.css" />

<script>
 window.onload = animate;

 var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
 var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

 function animate()
 {
 window.setInterval(slide,1000);
 }



 function slide()
 {
 var obj = document.getElementById("ball");
 var left = obj.style.left;
 if(left === ''){
    left = 0;
 }
 var wartosc = parseInt(left, 10);
 obj.style.left = (wartosc + 10) + "px";
 }

function Loop() {
if (left>canvas.width){
    var right = obj.style.right;
 if(right === ''){
    right = 0;
 }
 var wartosc = parseInt(right, 10);
 obj.style.right = (wartosc + 10) + "px";

 }
 </script>

 <style>
 #ball
 {
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
 }
 #mycanvas {border:1px solid #000000}
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <img src="ball.gif" id="ball" alt="Usmiech" width="30" height="30" />


  <canvas id=mycanvas width=600 height=50>Canvas Not Supported
  </canvas>

<body>
</html>
```

What I want it do to is for the image to be contained inside the canvas and to move left to right and when reached the right side of canvas to go back left and so on continuously.

However my problems are if can be done, I don't know how I can put the image on the canvas and then I can't make the image move to the right once it has reached the end off the canvas. I think the issue is my loop function, which is there to try to make it go to the right.

As you can see from the fiddle link, when I remove the loop function code it works. However it will only goes to the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/eCSb4/18/

Please can someone help me fix it?  :)

Comment: What about creating a `gif`?

Comment: What do you mean? The image I've chosen is a gif just for more special effects.

Comment: Like taking care of the animation using an animated gif instead of animating a jpeg

Comment: I think I know what you mean. Are you saying to create my own animated gif (like memes?) Either way I don't really no how I would proceed to do that. Is it not possible to do the way I'm trying to do. Would you know how?

Comment: Yeah, I know in Photoshop you can do it, but that's about as far as my experience goes. I'm not sure about doing the animation in html, but I feel like it would be a lot more complicated

Comment: Lol, yes it seems complicated indeed. Haha

Comment: Although, I mean all you want to do is move the image side to side, not like animate the image all on its own, right? Because if that is the case this may be pretty simple. I know with css3 you can translate an image side to side, but idk about inside a canvas

Comment: Yep pretty much, don't want to animate the image but I was wondering first of all if an image can be placed within the canvas? if so how can it be done?Anyways how would you go about doing it using css3?

Answer (score 1):

You can animate a spritesheet instead of a `.gif`.

The sequence is simple:

1. Clear the canvas,
2. Draw the next sprite in sequence and position it to advance across the canvas.
3. Wait a while (perhaps in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop).
4. Repeat #1.

Here's annotated code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// timing related vars
var nextTime=0;
var spriteCount=7;
var interval=700/spriteCount;
// sprite related vars
var sIndex=0;
var sw=60;
var sh=95;
var animationOn=true;

// current x,y position of sprite
var x=100;
var y=100;

// load the spritesheet
var ss=new Image();
ss.onload=start;
ss.src="http://i59.tinypic.com/jpkk6f.jpg";
function start(){

  // draw the first sprite
  ctx.drawImage(ss,sIndex*sw,0,sw,sh,x,y,sw,sh);

  // start the animation loop
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}

function animate(time){
  // wait for the specified interval before drawing anything
  if(time<nextTime || !animationOn){requestAnimationFrame(animate); return;}
  nextTime=time+interval;
  // draw the new sprite
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.drawImage(ss,sIndex*sw,0,sw,sh,x,y,sw,sh);
  // get the next sprite in sequence
  if(++sIndex>=spriteCount){sIndex=0;}
  // advance the sprite rightward
  x+=5;
  if(x>cw){x=-sw-10;}
  // request another animation loop
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I guess you can see my deleted answer. I think we both get fooled by the question's title and the presence of a `.gif` into the post. when looking at fiddle, it seems OP doesn't want to draw this animated gif, but just to move an image element "from left to right"...

Comment: @Kaiido, My answer both runs an animated spritesheet and moves from left to right. Isn't that what the OP wants? :-//